# GWT stand alone page?

Tags: gwt, unsubscribe

My app has an email newsletter and i'd like to implement an "Unsubscribe" option on the HTML email itself. This link would bring them to an isolated page that simply lets them know they've been unsubscribed, i'll grab their user info from URL parameters. There should be no way to access this page from within the app.

I was able to create an html file that's a sibling in the war folder to my host page and access it. How, in my app, do i detect that a user has accessed this page and then handle it? I don't need code to be shown to me, i just need a point in the right direction.

Comment: can you let us know what you have tried and share the relevant code?

Comment: Showing any code is pointless because I had no idea how to even begin. After mulling it over I realized it was pretty simple. After document ready, collect the user email from the URL parameter, and send it in a post request to a servlet. Once I receive it in the servlet it's a simple SQL statement. How's that sound?